# Text drawn on canvas get blurr after applying scaling and translation in android?

Tags: android

I have two Imageview One is BaseImage View and Another is StickerImageview,for merging both of them I applied scale and translation on matrix but after that image gets blurr to some extent and also text drawn on canvas get blurr.Also set the properties of paint like this,but there is no effect on text blurr.

```
textPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
textPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
textPaint.setDither(true);
textPaint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
```

Comment: how do you draw the text?

Comment: draw text using canvas.drawText(text,x,y,paint) method..

Comment: so after scaling the Canvas, text will not be blured